# Move a random sample of files from one folder to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have several folders of files, and I'm trying to move a sample of randomly selected files from one folder to another.
I'm working with the code below, but it's not quite running.

```
import os, random, shutil

source='folder_path_1'
dest='dest_folder_path'
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(source) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, f))]
no_of_files = round((len(onlyfiles)/5))

print(no_of_files)

for i in range(no_of_files):
    random_file=random.choice(os.listdir(source))
    source_file="%s\%s"%(source,random_file)
    dest_file=dest
    shutil.move(source_file,dest_file)
```

This yields multiple errors. First that `dest` is not defined, and if I then use the full paths the files don't move (no error, just no movement).

Comment: Please paste your error here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should look something like this. We could use `random.sample()` to get specific amount of random unique elements of our list (here `files`)

```
import os
import random
import shutil

source = 'folder_path_1'
dest = 'dest_folder_path'
files = os.listdir(source)
no_of_files = len(files) // 5

for file_name in random.sample(files, no_of_files):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source, file_name), dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, random, shutil

source ='C:\\Users\\OlavA\\Desktop\\Start'
destination ='C:\\Users\\OlavA\\Desktop\\Destination'

onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(source) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, f))]
no_of_files = round((len(onlyfiles)/5))

def main():
    for i in range(no_of_files):
        files = [filenames for (filenames) in os.listdir(source)]
        random_file = random.choice(files)
        shutil.move(f'{source}\\{random_file}', destination)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works, not the best code at all but it works.
Just remember to change your start path and destination path with your own, and you need `\\` instead of `\` in the path since it's a escape character.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the number of files I'd like to move

Comment: Yeah didn't see that he wanted that, changed it, works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea what shutil is but I got rid of it completely. I instead just used the built-in `open()` command. Here's my code:

```
import os, random

delete = True

source='source'
dest='destination'
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(source) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, f))]
no_of_files = round((len(onlyfiles)/5))

print(no_of_files)

for i in range(no_of_files):
    random_file=random.choice(os.listdir(source))
    source_file="%s/%s"%(source,random_file)
    dest_file=dest+'/'+random_file
    destination_for_file = open(dest_file,'wb+')
    source_for_file = open(source_file,'rb')
    destination_for_file.write(source_for_file.read())
    destination_for_file.close()
    #optional (to delete the source)
    if delete:
        os.remove(source_file)
```

> Note: if you don't want to delete the source, change `delete = True` to `delete = False`

I tested his on my linux machine. If you run Windows (in which case, consider using linux in some way [I dual-boot]), try to change the `'/'` to `'\\'`